# Incomplete documentation for Indian applying for Business visitor visa for UK

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, business-travel

I received a business invitation letter from a UK (London) company following a successful interview in UK four months ago. However my visa has expired and that company cannot sponsor me due to a sponsorship licensing problem (they never applied for a sponsorship licence), hence I could not take up the job offer.

Now the same company want me to visit them for project discussions with a view to my acting as an agent for them here in India. The company have stated in their invitation letter that they would bear my travel expenses for a stay of up to two months.

Currently I'm not working so unable to show tax returns and an employer letter to fulfil the documentary requirements for a business visitor visa application.

Can I apply without these?

Comment: Hi Gayot fow..company was in business past 100 but never applied for a sponsorship licence. they just want to me to visit their company and practice their procedures in order to follow their system, when i'm back to India after my visit i have to work as their agent. thank you for time.

Answer (score 2):

**Can I apply without these?**

Yes, you can apply without submitting tax returns and employment confirmations. 
The only documents [required *by law*](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/449508/20150803_immigration_rules_part_1_final.pdf) are...

1. The fee
2. A passport
3. Biometrics
4. Arguably, photographs
5. Arguably, the application form

All the other supporting documents are optional.  You will need to use your judgement and best practices to determine which [supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) to provide with your application.

I wanted to note however, that in the comments you wrote...

> they just want to me to visit their company and practice their
>   procedures in order to follow their system, when i'm back to India
>   after my visit i have to work as their agent.

This type of training does not appear to be an [approved activity](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/449641/20150803_Immigration_Rules_-_Appendix_V.pdfhttps://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/449641/20150803_Immigration_Rules_-_Appendix_V.pdf) and so it's likely that you should be applying for a different kind of visa.  You would be advised to carefully check that what you plan to do is an approved activity.